# Unable to access custom Activity field from a Task query

Tags: custom-field

We have created a custom Checkbox field on an Activity through the API.  But the field is not available on the task when I query as follows:

> SELECT Id, CallObject, MyCustomField__c FROM Task

Our code to create the task looks like this:

```
_sforceService = new SforceService();
var loginResult = _sforceService.login(_userName, _password + _token);
_sforceService.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;
_sforceService.SessionHeaderValue = new sforce.SessionHeader();
_sforceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;

_metadataService = new MetadataService();
_metadataService.Url = loginResult.metadataServerUrl;
_metadataService.SessionHeaderValue = new metaforce.SessionHeader();
_metadataService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;

var testCheckboxValue = new CustomField();
testCheckboxValue.fullName = "Activity.MyCustomField__c";
testCheckboxValue.label = "Test Checkbox Value";
testCheckboxValue.type = FieldType.Checkbox;
testCheckboxValue.typeSpecified = true;
testCheckboxValue.defaultValue = "false";

var saveResult = _metadataService.createMetadata(new Metadata[] {testCheckboxValue});​
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is no standard object Activity in your line: `testCheckboxValue.fullName = "Activity.MyCustomField__c";` The standard object is called Task. I'm surprised your createmetadata call didn't fail with an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the Field-level permissions for the Custom Field. When you create your custom field it will not be visible to any user.

I have found a solution in the developer forums here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000AVifIAG.

Unfortunately this requires you to deploy the custom field definition and permissions in XML, so it is a little less straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the field is not created, since as crop1645 stated you need to use task instead of activity. Did you verify saveResult to check if your call has really succeeded?